# How to install Rodeo IDE in Anaconda python distribution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, anaconda, rodeo

I have a 64bit anaconda python distribution version  2.3 with python 3.4.3 installed on windows 7 machine. I searched about installing rodeo on top of this but seems like "conda install rodeo" wont work, so i did "pip install rodeo".

```
"pip install rodeo" gave me the following message "Successfully installed rodeo".
```

But when i type rodeo in cmd to start rodeo it is giving an error saying

```
"failed to create process."
```

& i am not able to start rodeo.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yhat has released a native desktop version of Rodeo recently. It will be better than the web version. This can be easily installed by downloading the installable from their website mentioned below.

https://www.yhathq.com/products/rodeo/downloads

Answer (score 14):

## Updated Answer (as of 2016-6-8)

Rodeo has been undergoing a significant re-write since the latest major release, **v1.3** which is the [currently downloadable version](https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo) on yhat's website.

I recommend checking out the latest release, **v2.0**, downloadable from the [Rodeo project page on github](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo).

---

Here's how I set up Anaconda and Rodeo

1. Install the latest version of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)
2. [Create a fresh virtual environment](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment) which includes jupyter. `conda create --name datasci jupyter`
3. Install the [latest version of Rodeo](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo)
4. Open Rodeo and set the Python Path to your fresh anaconda virtual environment. (In my case //anaconda/envs/datasci/bin/python)

[image]

If you're not sure what path to set,

1. Open Terminal
2. Activate your virtual environment `source activate datasci`
3. Run `which python`

More details in the [Rodeo docs](http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/).  And keep checking github for version updates as they're coming almost daily at this point.

Comment: Super helpful; was going to ask about how to use venv with rodeo and this is the answer. :)

Comment: If you already have an environment working but missing Jupyter you want to use run:  conda install -n spatial_env jupyter

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you need to make sure you are using pip as seen by Anaconda. To get around this I have an alias set up in my .bash_aliases file (not sure what the equivalent is in windows) to call anaconda's version of pip:

```
alias pip-ana='/home/usr/anaconda/bin/pip'
```

That means that I use the command `pip-ana` to install things to Anaconda's python environment rather than simply `pip` as that defaults to an alternative python environment. So to solve your problem, make sure you are using the correct `pip` by calling the executable file from `anaconda/bin`.

Comment: I only have 1 python related installation in my system which is from anaconda distribution. So pip install should refer to pip from anaconda only right? Also i can see the rodeo.exe in C:\Program Files\anaconda\Scripts

Comment: Just to clarify, you are typing `rodeo .` right? The `.` is important as this provides a directory as an argument.

Comment: Are you sure your path points to the anaconda directory? In my bashrc (not sure what the windows equivalent is) I have the following: `export PATH="/home/usr/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` which was put there by anaconda.

Comment: After reinstalling anaconda & launching rodeo with "rodeo ." worked.

Answer (score 0):

you could type 'which pip' to ensure you are running correct version.

also the command in the instructions to give you command line access to Rodeo did not work for me. I wrote a new command which does work. I'd be happy to share that with you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).