# Unable to import sklearn and statsmodels from Anaconda from windows 10 pro

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda, statsmodels, rodeo

I'm relatively new to python, so please excuse my ignorance on what could be a very easy fix. I am running python 3.6 through the Rodeo IDE, and it has been great, as it is similar to R-Studio (which I am very familiar with). As an aspiring data scientist, I am trying to learn how to fit regression and time series models to data, and all of the tutorials that I have found all say that I need various packages, all of which should be included in the Anaconda library. After downloading and re-downloading Python, Rodeo, and Anaconda, and trying various online fixes, I have been unable to successfully load the scikit-learn  and the statsmodels modules.

```
#here is everything I have tried.
#using pip
! pip install 'statsmodels'
! pip install 'scikit-learn'
! pip install 'sklearn'
```

I don't get any errors here, and to be honest I'm kind of confused as to what this actually does, but I have seen many people online always suggest that this is a big problem when trying to import modules.

```
#using import
import sklearn
import statsmodels
from sklearn import datasets
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

all of the above give me the same error:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels'

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last)
ipython-input-184-6030a6549dc0 in module()

----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels'

I have tried to set my working directory to the Anaconda 3 file that has all of the packages and rerunning the above code with no success.

I'm thinking that the most likely problem has to do with my inexperience, and it is probably a simple fix. Is it possible that the IDE is bad or anaconda just doesn't like me?

So keeping all of the above in mind, the question is, how can I import these modules successfully so that I can access their functionality?

Comment: Run "pip show statsmodels" and tell us what it returns.

Comment: In command prompt, it said 

"You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

Comment: Following which I updated pip and tried everything again and was still unsuccessful. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: 
After installing packages with pip, try closing and reopening your IDE/Jupyter Notebook and try again.

This is a known bug that Jake VanderPlas outlined [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/)

Option 2: 
Don't put quotations around your pip messages.

```
!pip install -U statsmodels
!pip install scikit-learn
```

Option 3:
Also are you using Anaconda? If you are, you should already have scikit-learn.  If you are trying inside Rodeo, I think you need to set your path inside Rodeo. Open Rodeo and set the Python Path to your fresh anaconda. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935714/how-to-install-rodeo-ide-in-anaconda-python-distribution)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your prompt response. I tried it, and received the same error. "ImportError: No module named 'sklearn' ". Do you know of anything else I could try?

Comment: I added some more feedback. Let me know if it works and we can try something else if it doesnt.

Comment: Upon reinstalling and re-configuring anaconda, it worked with no problems. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Accept my answer if it helped you please.